# KO data-binding "text:" to a function with a parameter

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible in any way to do the following without have to pass through temporary observables / computed observables?  I have common data which is used for lookups to display data:

```
<span data-bind="text: lookupContactName(31)"></span>
```

result: function is exectuded, parameter is found, logic ok, and computed full name is returned, but not displayed (probably since no observable)

```
<span data-bind="text: lookupContactName(contactId)"></span>
```

result: contactId is not parsed so the correct parameter value is not visible.

I suppose for this to work correctly i would need to create custom bindings?

in general: i started doubting a bit whether or not my approach to load data only once and try to match up id's is a good approach.  any views?  i'm better of creating joined db tables / views / SP's?

Thanks,
J.

here, are the relevant code pieces i'm using...  I will learn jsfiddle for future help.

ALL ALERT's are returning the expected values... but still the text data-binding doesn't receive the value

A common data library:

```
customers.Contact = function () {
    var self = this;

    id = ko.observable();
    title = ko.observable();
    givenname = ko.observable();
    surname = ko.observable();
    fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return title()+". "+givenname()+" "+surname();
    });

    return {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        givenname: givenname,
        surname: surname,
        fullName: fullName
    };
};
customers.ContactList = function () {

    var self = this;

    contactList = ko.observableArray([]); //.publishOn("ContactList");

    loadContactData = function () {
        var self = this;

        customers.helperDataService.getContactData(loadContactDataCallBack);
    };

    loadContactDataCallBack = function (json) {
        var self = this;

        $.each(json, function (i, p) {

            var contact = new customers.Contact().id(p.Id)
                                                  .title(p.Title)
                                                  .givenname(p.Name)
                                                  .surname(p.Surname);

            contactList.push(contact);
        });

    };

    lookupContactName = function (id) {
        var self = this;

       alert("value to be found: "+id);

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(contactList(), function (contact) {
            alert("SEARCH:  contactid: " + contact.id() + " - " + "id: " + id);
            if (contact.id() === id) {
                alert("FOUND: contactid: " + contact.id() + " - " + "id: " + id);
                alert("value:" + contact.fullName());
                return contact.fullName();
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        loadContactData: loadContactData,
        lookupContactName: lookupContactName
    };
};
```

Which is called from here... (i changed it to contactId() and this passes the correct value to the function)

```
<div>Creator: <span data-bind="text: lookupContactName(contactId())"></span></div>
```

Comment: I'm just curious... what does `lookupContactName` think its parameter is if you use `lookupContactName(contactId)`? Does it just get the string "contactId"?

Comment: In general this should work. Can you maybe put together a JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Changed lookupContactName(contactId) into lookupContactName(contactId()) this gives the correct id instead of just not returning anything.  thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4):

If your `<span data-bind="text: lookupContactName(contactId())"></span>` is in a foreach loop then you need to prepend the method with $root or else it will look for "lookupContactName" within the array it is looping trough.

Try:

```
<div>Creator: <span data-bind="text: $root.lookupContactName(contactId())"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you lookup function doesn't return a value

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(contactList(), function (contact) {
// some checking code
    return contact.fullName();
});
```

your "return" is related to inner function passed to arrayForEach utility method. You need a code like this

```
var result;
ko.utils.arrayForEach(contactList(), function (contact) {
// some checking code
    result = contact.fullName();
});
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure to understand what is your problem here. You can do something like that if you want:

```
function lookupContactName(cid) {
    var obj = ... // Find your object by id;
    return ko.computed(function () {
       return obj.name() + obj.lastname();
    });
}
```

It should just work.

Comment: sorry guys, i have to study jsfiddle a bit, never used it...  i made a bit of progress, but still no luck.  I will copy paste the relevant code, hope you understand better.

Comment: hey guys I've found a solution (bypass).  don't understand why, but for some reason the return only works outside of the array loop...